# Mongoose how to find specific value

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

After a lot of reading, I am stuck.
the code I posted here, is the implementation of a store database I am trying to make.
in every store, we have some fields. I am interested in doing something with the items array, that contains JSON variables.
I want to filter the items through three filters, firstly by the store ID, secondly by the category ID, and the last filter will be the semi category ID.

I want to send the data from the front end, meaning I supply `STOREID`, the `CategoryID`, and the `SemiCategoryID`.
after receiving the data at the back end side, I am expecting to receive only the relevant items according to the data supplied by the front end.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a1844b5685cb50a38adf5bb" --> **ID of the STORE**
    },
    "name": "ACE",
    "user_id": "59e4c41105d1f6227c1771ea",
    "imageURL": "none",
    "rating": 5,
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "NirCohen",
            "categoryID": "5a0c2d292235680012bd12c9",
            "semiCatID": "5a0c2d5a2235680012bd12ca",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a1958181cd8a208882a80f9"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "he",
            "categoryID": "5a0c2d292235680012bd12c9",
            "semiCatID": "5a0c2d5a2235680012bd12ca",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a1973c40e561e08b8aaf2b2"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "a",
            "categoryID": "5a0c2d292235680012bd12c9",
            "semiCatID": "5a0c2d5a2235680012bd12ca",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a197439bc1310314c4c583b"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "aaa",
            "categoryID": "5a0c2d292235680012bd12c9",
            "semiCatID": "5a0c2d5a2235680012bd12ca",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a197474558a921bb043317b"
            }
        },
    ],
    "__v": 9
}
```

and I want the Backend to return the filtered items according to the query.
The problem is, I am not managing to get the CORRECT query.

your help will be much appreciated,

thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you try to explain better what it is you want to happen?
Where is the function calling mongo? What is your result and what is your intended result?

Comment: currently there is a basic query mongoose that pop only the store, i want to get all the 'items' (names) that match the categoryID and subcategoryID.
I want to get a json list\array with all the items (name field) that match to the store ID (that i successed already) and match to the other parameters (categoryID, semiCatyegoryID)

Comment: So you are fetching an object, only get the storeID but you want to populate the Store object? check this out http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Hi, i got the storeID, categoryID and samiCategoryID i just need to know to query to filter by this id's.

Comment: Hi, @nircohen can you check this out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274306/mongoose-how-to-do-a-find-with-two-or-conditions and on the place of `or` you need to use `and`.

Comment: Multiple query example -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272824/combine-two-or-queries-with-and-in-mongoose

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you are doing something like this:

```
Store.find({}).then(..);
```

If you only want to find the stores where categoryID is equal to the variable myCategory, you could filter them out by using:

```
Store.find({semiCatID: myCategory}).then(..);
```

Please let me know if this is not what you are after, then we can keep trying to figure this out together.

**EDIT**: So you are sending the variables `StoreID`, `CategoryID` and `SemiCategoryID` from the frontend. Receive them in the backend, and want to filter your database collection matching all three fields?
If so.. then I think all you have to do is change your current query:

```
store.findOne({ _id: req.body.userID }, (err, store) => { console.log(store); });
```

To something like:

```
store.findOne({
    _id: req.body.userID,
    storeID: req.body.StoreID,
    categoryID: req.body.CategoryID,
    semiCategoryID: req.body.SemiCategoryID
}, (err, store) => { console.log(store); });
```

This way, the objects you get back from mongo must match all four criterias given from the frontend.

Comment: Hi, first thanks. I eddited my post in order to make my question more clearly.

For now this is my qurey  ....
store.findOne({ _id: req.body.userID }, (err, store) => {
      console.log(store);
});

Comment: @nircohen I've edited the answer, hopefully to achieve your desired results.

Comment: I tried you query, if you didnt saw the categoryID and semiCategoryID there are in the array that call 'items' so should i use items.categoryID and items.semiCategoryID ?
Thanks alot for help!

Comment: in the query I tried to do this ""items.categoryID": req.body.category,"
and its not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I Understood your question here is my answer to it you can use **findById**

```
Store.findById({//store id}).then(..);
```

or

```
Store.findOne({_id:ObjectID(storeID)}).then(..);
```

Comment: I dont understand your answer.
because, I dont need to filter by the 3 IDs? (Store,Category,SemiCategory) as i see its looks like your answer will give me only the store values.. no?